# JavaScript runtime error: 'launchCenter' is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net

I'm doing some modification work on an old Web program and I came across the warning message above during testing.

Here is part of the code for reference:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="PIB_ModelMast.aspx.vb" Inherits="NetApps.PIB_MODELMAST" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <title>PIB_MODELMAST</title>
    <meta content="True" name="vs_showGrid">
    <meta content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1" name="GENERATOR">
    <meta content="Visual Basic .NET 7.1" name="CODE_LANGUAGE">
    <meta content="JavaScript" name="vs_defaultClientScript">
    <meta content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" name="vs_targetSchema">
    <script language="javascript">
function confirm_delete() 
    { 
    if (confirm("Do you want to delete record?")==true) 
    return true; 
    else 
    return false; 
    }

    function confirm_Edit(id) {
        var theForm = document.forms[0]
        traschURL="PIB_MODELADD.aspx?ID=" + id
        traschWin = launchCenter(traschURL, 'traschWin', 650, 900)
        return false;
    }

    </script>

</HEAD>
<body MS_POSITIONING="GridLayout">
    <form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
        <TABLE id="Table1" style="Z-INDEX: 101; LEFT: 8px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 8px" borderColor="aqua"
            height="50" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" bgColor="darkblue" border="1">
            <TR>
                <TD>
                    <center><FONT face="Arial" color="#ffffff" size="5"><STRONG>MODEL AND LINE MASTER 
                                MAINTENANCE</STRONG></FONT></center>
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
        <TABLE id="Table2" style="Z-INDEX: 102; LEFT: 8px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 80px; HEIGHT: 56px"
            cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" bgColor="lightgrey" border="0">
            <TR>
                <TD style="WIDTH: 121px"><STRONG><FONT face="Arial"></FONT></STRONG></TD>
                <TD style="WIDTH: 125px"><FONT face="Arial"><STRONG>MODEL</STRONG></FONT></TD>
                <TD style="WIDTH: 664px"><asp:textbox id="ModelText" runat="server" Height="27px" Width="469px" Font-Size="Small"></asp:textbox></TD>
                <TD style="WIDTH: 209px"><asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" Width="95px" Text="Filter" Font-Bold="True" Height="35px"></asp:button></TD>
                <TD style="WIDTH: 74px"><asp:button id="Button2" runat="server" Width="96px" Text="Add New" Font-Bold="True" Height="35px"></asp:button></TD>
                <TD style="WIDTH: 138px"></TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
        <asp:datagrid id="DataGrid1" style="Z-INDEX: 103; LEFT: 16px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 168px"
            runat="server" Width="100%" GridLines="Horizontal" BorderColor="Aqua" OnDeleteCommand="DataGrid1_DeleteCommand"
            DataKeyField="ID" CellPadding="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" BackColor="PaleTurquoise">
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#000099"></FooterStyle>
            <SelectedItemStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="MidnightBlue"></SelectedItemStyle>
            <EditItemStyle BackColor="PaleTurquoise"></EditItemStyle>
            <AlternatingItemStyle Font-Size="X-Small" Font-Names="Arial" BackColor="Wheat"></AlternatingItemStyle>
            <ItemStyle Font-Size="X-Small" Font-Names="Arial"></ItemStyle>
            <HeaderStyle Font-Size="X-Small" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" BackColor="#000099"></HeaderStyle>
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundColumn Visible="False" DataField="ID" SortExpression="ID" HeaderText="Id"></asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Model" SortExpression="Model" HeaderText="Model">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="200px"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Line" SortExpression="Line" HeaderText="Line">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="200px"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:BoundColumn>
               <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Process" SortExpression="Process" HeaderText="Process">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="200px"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="PZone" SortExpression="PZone" HeaderText="PZone">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="200px"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:ButtonColumn Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:ButtonColumn>
                <asp:ButtonColumn Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:ButtonColumn>
            </Columns>
        </asp:datagrid></form>
</body>
```

The remainder of the code is used to build a GridView.
The GridView will have a column with Delete Button and Edit Button for each row. Clicking Edit on any row will cause this warning message to appear.

```
JavaScript runtime error: 'launchCenter' is undefined
```

'launchCenter' appears in the confirm_Edit function of the code and I tried to comment it out, because my initial thought was it was an unused code since it was not defined. But that ends up causing the Edit Button in my GridView to stop working.

Also, even though I have the warning message, if I click Continue the program continues to function properly and I can edit and save changes in the GridView. The same goes for the live version. No issues detected.

Now I just want to fix the code so that the message won't appear. Any help? I'll add in more of my code if necessary.

Comment: Where is the `launchCenter()` you defined?

Comment: That's the problem... Its not defined in this .aspx document. I'm not sure how to define it since this is a program made by an old developer before me.

Comment: Try chaining it to `traschWin = '';`

Comment: Do you mean change it from `traschWin = launchCenter(traschURL, 'traschWin', 650, 900)` to `traschWin = ''`? Tried that, the Edit button can't work.

Comment: That's quite hard to figure it out the problem because you didn't provided enough information. You may try to check where traschWin is used and define a `launchCenter()` which returns a correct value.

Comment: Let me try and put in the full code. Maybe that will help.